# why browser sends only 1 request for 4 image tags?

Tags: html, browser, http-caching

I noticed a strange behavior.
There are 4 img tags on html pages but only one http get request goes in network panel .

why is this behavior ?
I thought even if there are 4 same resource request atleast 4 request will be sent and last 3 request will be returned from cache after 1st request completion.

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>

  </head>
  <body>


<h1>for 4 Image only one http request was sent</h1>
<img src="lily.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
<img src="lily.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
<img src="lily.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
<img src="lily.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">

  


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only refering to one external resource, namely "lily.jpg".

The fact that you're using it 4 times doesn't make the browser re-download the same thing 4 times.